# Symfony FOSUserBundle : keep other forms' data after login

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, parameter-passing, fosuserbundle

I have a page with several forms, it is possible to login from that page, when a user logs in from it, I set my security.yml file to redirect to said page with

```
use_referer: true
```

However, I would like to keep other form's input values, but I have yet to find a working a solution for this matter..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not possible through the FOSUserBundle. You have to create own layer over the forms you want to "save" before the login happens. I can imagine that values are stored in the SessionStorage or LocalStorage when user's typing. So you have to use JavaScript. When the page is loaded, the stored data is restored to the form. When user hits a submit button, storage will be cleared.

Comment: Thanks ! Found my way with by adding variable to Symfony sessions and resetting them if user reaches certain pages where he can define them again.